# Remove certain rows without iterating the whole file line by line in Python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, line

I have the dataset like below :

```
Category,Date,Id,Amount
Risk A,11/12/2020,1,-10
Risk A,11/13/2020,2,10
Risk A,11/14/2020,3,22
Risk A,11/15/2020,4,32
Total Risk A : 4  ----- needs to be removed
Risk C,11/9/2020,5,43
Risk C,11/10/2020,6,22
Risk C,11/11/2020,7,11
Risk C,11/12/2020,8,-50
Total Risk C : 4   ----- needs to be removed
Risk D,11/12/2020,9,3
Risk D,11/13/2020,10,1
Risk D,11/14/2020,11,3
Risk D,11/15/2020,12,4
Risk D,11/9/2020,13,55
Risk D,11/10/2020,14,32
Total Risk C : 6      ----- needs to be removed
```

In between the data rows , there are some specific total(summary) rows, which I need to remove from the file.
Looking for a better way to remove these rows, without iterating the file line by line in python.As I have few thousand rows and its a time taking to remove some summary lines.
Kindly suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to perform string substitution:

```
import re
t = """Category,Date,Id,Amount
Risk A,11/12/2020,1,-10
Risk A,11/13/2020,2,10
Risk A,11/14/2020,3,22
Risk A,11/15/2020,4,32
Total Risk A : 4  ----- needs to be removed
Risk C,11/9/2020,5,43
Risk C,11/10/2020,6,22
Risk C,11/11/2020,7,11
Risk C,11/12/2020,8,-50
Total Risk C : 4   ----- needs to be removed
Risk D,11/12/2020,9,3
Risk D,11/13/2020,10,1
Risk D,11/14/2020,11,3
Risk D,11/15/2020,12,4
Risk D,11/9/2020,13,55
Risk D,11/10/2020,14,32
Total Risk C : 6      ----- needs to be removed"""

print(re.sub(r'\nTotal.*','', t))
```

`re.sub` will find all the parts of the file that matches the pattern (`r'\nTotal.*'`: a newline followhed by the word "Total", followed by any character until the end of line), and replace them with ''.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know which lines to remove without looking at each one individually, as there's no way to tell which lines are summaries and which aren't without interacting with each individual line.  (There are some small optimizations that could be implemented, like skipping the next line after a summary line if two can't happen in a row, but the impact of these would be minimal at best).  A likely more fruitful way to speed up the program would be to, instead of going through the file line-by-line, read the entire program into memory, edit it as a string or list, and then to write it all into a new file at once.  This would be faster than what it sounds like you are doing, as input-output operations take much longer than those that only act on variables in memory.